# How do disable "Response receipts" with on Google Form with a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm having issues with a Google Form / Scripts feature.

I'm creating a form through a script enabling mail collection with the function "setCollectEmail". But when this function is enabled automatically it allows respondents to receive a copy of the responses.

I need to collect the emails but not allow them to receive a copy of the responses.

How can I disable this feature through a script?

Could anybody help me?

[image: Response receipts - Google Form]

Comment: AFAIK,if you do `https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/messageId` it will automatically change into the id you view in the browser (not the one returned by the API). I'm not sure if you can use `messageId` that way to search in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the first checkbox that says "Response receipts" and you can disable it.

It appears that this cannot be done in Apps Script, but [it is on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78605510), so there may be a chance the developers will add this feature.